# Iframe not loading on IE9

Tags: jquery, .net, iframe

I'm using .net platform,
I have an iframe on my Master page.

```
<iframe id="NewsFeedFrame" name="NewsFeedFrame" style="height: 1042px; border: 0px solid;
                    overflow: hidden;" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

and on document.ready event in javascript I'm loading the iframe like this.

```
$("iframe").attr("src", "abc.aspx");
```

but on Internet explorer this thing does not load anything.
Does anybody having any solution???

Comment: Any error on your debug console?

Comment: no errors, just a blank div

Comment: @MayurMohite If this helped you then you can accept this as correct to help further users. Just Tick the transparent arrow which is below The down arrow ,left to starting of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) there is some documentation from IE9 that may help to understand. Thanks to @Ben Amada for sharing it.

---

After almost a week of going crazy day after day I found it out.

The problem with IE9 is no specifically with the javascript code in the iframes. Not even with the javascript in iframes added by javascript or any library (I have lots of js libraries and plugins that could be screwing IE9).

The problem is when you move the iframe or one ancestor through the DOM. IE9 will excecute the code in the page loaded in the iframe as many times as moves you make. Each time (but the last one) will have Object, String, Array and others undefined (and other bugs too).

Example:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", "www.example.com").attr("id", "myIframe");
iframe.appendTo("body");
$("#myIframe").appendTo("form:eq(0)");
```

The javascript code in "www.example.com" will be executed once with the error described above and then once with no errors.

With the following code the code will be excecuted just once and correctly:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", "www.example.com").attr("id", "myIframe");
iframe.appendTo("form:eq(0)");
```

Comment: I think it's working properly...thanx for the solution man!
Saved a lot of time :)

Comment: @MayurMohite If this helped you then you can accept this as correct to help further users. Just Tick the transparent arrow which is below The down arrow ,left to starting of my answer.